# Is it normal for modern French books to be written in the present tense?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, littérature, passé-simple

A few years ago I was given a copy of the Hunger Games (the third one) in French, which is aimed at teenagers. However I was surprised to see that the narration is entirely in the present tense. The first sentence reads:

> Je baisse les yeux vers mes chaussures.

Is this normal for modern French books, or was I given an easy version since I'm still learning French? If it is normal, at what point (target audience, genre) do French books start being written in the passé simple? Also is the passé composé used at all in literature?

Comment: The original English version is written in present tense (*I stare down at my shoes...*), so it's natural that the translation is in present tense too.

Comment: Ah well I guess that's a bad example. But judging from the answers it seems that it's more normal to use the present tense in French writing than in English

Answer (score 2):

Il est habituel d'utiliser le présent pour raconter des événements passés. On appelle cela le « présent de narration » ou « présent historique ».
Voir par exemple sur [TV5Monde](http://parlons-francais.tv5monde.com/webdocumentaires-pour-apprendre-le-francais/Memos/Grammaire/p-507-lg0-Le-present-de-narration.htm).
Ce n'est pas spécifique à la littérature, ni au français moderne.

Par contre le passé simple est peu employé en français contemporain, il est d'un registre assez soutenu, il n'est pratiquement pas employé à l'oral.

---

The *présent de l'indicatif* is usual to talk about past events. We call this the *présent de narration*  or  *présent historique*.  See examples on [TV5Monde](http://parlons-francais.tv5monde.com/webdocumentaires-pour-apprendre-le-francais/Memos/Grammaire/p-507-lg0-Le-present-de-narration.htm).
This is not specific to literature or to modern French.
The *présent historique* is commonly used [in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present), [in German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historisches_Pr%C3%A4sens), [in Spanish](http://www.blogdeespanol.com/2014/01/presente-historico/) an I expect in lots of other languages.

The *passé simple* would not be used to tell a story in a modern literature, it is not much used in modern French.
The *passé composé* or the *imparfait* could be used, but the *present de l'indicatif* is usually preferred, even in formal writing.

Comment: "Par contre le passé simple est peu employé en français contemporain".  Pas d'accord, il reste le temps préféré de la narration au passé.  L'énorme majorité des romans que je lis l'utilisent.  Les conteurs l'utilisent.  Les auteurs de chansons, même pour enfants, l'utilisent. J'ai regardé une fois les livres pour enfants pré-lecteurs que j'avais à la maison, la moitié de ceux écrit au passé utilisait le passé simple, et pas uniquement les classiques qui sont encombrés de leur historique.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Et les livres d'enfants que j'ai sous les yeux sont plutôt au passé composé... on ne lit pas les mêmes !

Comment: Ces livres pour pré-lecteurs sont maintenant archivés, mes enfants ayant grandis.  Si j'y pense la prochaine fois que je passe à la bibliothèque, je ferai un sondage sur leurs rayons. (Une partie d'entre eux étaient des classiques de l'école des loisirs mais j'avais vérifié que le passé simple était aussi utilisé dans ceux de rédaction plus récente)

Comment: @Unfrancophone Ça m’intéresserais. En particulier les romans récentes de fiction

Comment: @Laure Comme un Australien, je dirais pas que le présent de l’indicative est *fréquent*.

Comment: @Miguel Le présent de l'indicatif est un temps du français, j'ai mal rédigé en anglais je corrige, en anglais et dans les autres langues on va parler du présent tout court.

Comment: Donc j'ai voulu dire *le présent*... mais quand-même c'est pas fréquent en les romains anglais.

Comment: @Miguel I suggest you have a look at the questions and answers on the historic present on [English Language](http://english.stackexchange.com/), some on [writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/tense-of-literary-essay). It's probably as much used in English as it is in French.

Comment: @Miguel Just picked two novels from my shelves: it is used intertwined with the past by David Lodge (British) and Kathryn Stockett's *The help* (US). Margaret Atwood (Canadian) uses it her most her novels, and not only in the *Handmaid's Tale* as pointed out by the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present), article that also has a quote from Dickens.

Comment: Pour fins de discussion, un [exemple](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Je+baisse+les+yeux%2CJe+baissai+les+yeux&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CJe%20baisse%20les%20yeux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bje%20baisse%20les%20yeux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJe%20baisse%20les%20yeux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CJe%20baissai%20les%20yeux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bje%20baissai%20les%20yeux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJe%20baissai%20les%20yeux%3B%2Cc0). Il manque d'espace pour ajouter un lien incluant le passé composé.